# Relative center of relative group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

This might be an easy question.  Let $p: X \rightarrow S$ be a relative group scheme.  In particular the fibers are group schemes.  I want to know if there are constructions like the ``relative center'' or ''relative automorphism group'' and how one would define them in a good way.

Comment: The relative automorphism group should be easy enough: start with the category of schemes over $S$, pass to the category of its group objects, and take automorphisms there.  The center... I am not sure if there is a categorical way to describe it, but I'll think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. One is to define these objects first as a functor, and then to investigate whether the functors are representable. This answer is about the first problem.

This is dealt with in SGA 3 Exposé I 2.1-2.3 from the point of view of group-objects in the category of set-valued contravariant functors on an arbitrary category. For the case of group schemes over a base $S$ this would be functors on the category of schemes over $S$ with values in groups.

Automorphism functors can then be defined in a straightforward way as invertible morphisms from an object to itself in the same category. One can also define group actions, centralizers and normalizers of actions, and finally the center of a group as the centralizer of the action of the group on itself by conjugation.

For automorphisms, giving an element of $\text{Aut}_S(G)(T)$, for an $S$-scheme $T$, comes down to giving a family of automorphisms of the group $\text{Hom}(T',G)$ for every scheme $T'$ over $T$, in such a way that is compatible with the transition maps induced by morphisms $T''\rightarrow T'$ of schemes over $T$. This is the same as giving an automorphism of the functor $G$ restricted to the category of schemes over $T$.

Similarly, a functorial point $\text{Cent}(G)(T)$ is an element of the group $\text{Hom}_S(T,G)$ such that conjugation by every pullback of it via a map $T' \rightarrow T$ of $S$-schemes induces the identity on $\text{Hom}_{T}(T',G_T)$.

These are the correct ways to define these objects. Whether they are representable as (group) schemes is another matter, and I don't know the current state of the art. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will complete this answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!

Comment: By the way, I found a reference for some of this.  For the center (or more generally, centralizer) it's the examples in SGA3 VIII.6.  If $X$ is essentially free over $S$, then the functor is representable.  In particular if $p$ is affine and the ring of $X$ is locally a free module over $S$ then $p$ is essentially free.  For automorphisms (or more generally, homomorphisms), SGA 3 XIV.7.3.1 has a discussion.  In particular $Hom(G, H)$ is representable in characteristic zero if $G$ is reductive and $H$ smooth, quasiprojective, with affine fibers.

Comment: If $G$ is not reductive then one still can represent $\Hom(G, H)$ by an ind-scheme, the argument is in one of Conrad's book Pseudoreductive groups Lemma A.8.13.